# Do I need to restart Tomcat when changing .class files

Tags: tomcat, .class-file

If I deposit new .class files in my WEB-INF/classes directory, do I need to restart Tomcat or can it wait for the next start to consider changes ?
Will I have some issues from not reloading the context or the Tomcat server ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to apply your changes, then you must restart it